# Only half of my videos play in UIWebView

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

I have created an app in Xcode 7 Beta 5 that is pretty basic and works well to a certain point. I have a `UIWebView` that is pointing to an HTML file that I have in the project.  It is just an app that has a library of 36 videos. The app starts a runs great but I can only play half of the videos.  Originally I thought the format must be wrong on the second half, but they are all the same. The code I used for linking the web view to the HTML file is as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType:"html")!)))
}
```

I am having no issues with this part. It loads fast and all the videos are present.
The issue is that once I play half of the videos the other half has a line through the play button and won't play. The weird thing is that if I restart the app on my phone the bottom half will play.  It seems like I can only play a max of fifteen videos and the rest will have the line through them.  I can make this happen in any order.  The HTML code is as follows for each video:

```
    <video src="SSWGV1-iphone6.mp4" width="320" height="240" controls></video>
```

I have no idea what is going on. Is it a memory issue? Cache? Any help would be greatly appreciated.